# Running Iphone App on Ipad

Tags: iphone

how do you make the Iphone app run as 2X on Ipad automatically?

Building the app as both Iphone and Ipad would require you to build the Ipad from scratch right?

I prefer the 2x mode on IPad, but the build says its only geared toward Iphone. I like the user to use this app for both Iphone and Ipad, and 2x inside IPAD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any app built for the iPhone will run on iPad either at default size or zoomed in to 2X size, but you can't control what the user selects.

It is possible to create a universal application where you design an interface for both the iPhone and the iPad within the same app. The alternative is creating an entirely separate app for the iPad.

Comment: I did target device for both iphone and Ipad, now 2x mode is gone, the display looks odd and funny on Ipad.  and I don't want to do extra works to make Ipad work.

Comment: If you don't want to do any extra work just target iPhone. It will still run default or zoomed 2X on an iPad. By adding the iPad target you're now creating a universal app, so you would have to design a separate UI (and add new resources) for iPad users.

Answer (score 2):

Whether to run an iPhone app in 1x or 2x mode on an iPad is entirely up to the user. It's not something you can control. If you want it to be fullscreen always on an iPad, you'll need to make your app handle iPads.

Comment: I did target device for both iphone and Ipad, now 2x mode is gone, the display looks odd and funny on Ipad. and I don't want to do extra works to make Ipad work.